# How to convert to datetime in sql server when using two varchar columns

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am having trouble converting two columns into one datetime field.  The columns are in the following format DateColumn = '20150130' and the TimeColumn is in the following format '81244' or '113404' with no leading zeros given.  I have the following format so far which looks like a proper datetime format to me.  However, for whatever reason I cannot Cast it into a datetime.  I get the following error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(DATECOLUMN, 4) +'-' + LEFT(RIGHT(DATECOLUMN, 4), 2) + '-' +  LEFT(RIGHT(DATECOLUMN, 2), 2) + ' ' + 
   LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(TIMECOLUMN AS varchar), 6),2) + ':' +
   LEFT(RIGHT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(TIMECOLUMN AS varchar), 6),4), 2) + ':' +
   RIGHT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(TIMECOLUMN AS varchar), 6), 2) + ':000000' AS DATETIME) 
   FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: The biggest issue is that you are storing datetime information as strings. This is a very common and truly awful decision. Look at how absurd your query is to take this unvalidated data and turn it back into a datatype that it should be in the first place. And you should always specify the size of your varchars instead of letting the default size happen.

Comment: I assume when you say "no leading zeroes given" you're referring to only the hours, correct?

Comment: At the risk of helping you continue down this route (rather than paying heed to Sean's comment), I would point out that times in strings are usually seen as `00:00:00.0000000`, not `00:00:00:000000`.

Comment: Fix the schema. If you want to store date and time separately, use a `date` and a `time` field. As it is, `TIMECOLUMN` is useless for searching as `81244` comes after `130000`. Changing `DATECOLUMN` is easy - a simple `cast(DATECOLUMN as date)` will return a valid `date`

Comment: Correct only hours have no leading zeros.  And unfortunately/frustratingly fixing the schema is not an option

Comment: Sorry the fields are numeric as I just found out using the below solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with this representation indeed. Here is a working statement with variables, you can change them to use column names instead:

```
declare @DATECOLUMN varchar(8), @TIMECOLUMN varchar(6);
select @DATECOLUMN = 20150130, @TIMECOLUMN = 81244;

select datetimefromparts (substring(@datecolumn, 1,4), substring(@datecolumn, 5,2), substring(@datecolumn, 7,2)
                      , cast(@timecolumn as int) / 10000, (cast(@timecolumn as int) % 10000) / 100, 
                          cast (@timecolumn as int) % 100, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with your sample data.

```
declare @date varchar(10) = '20150130'
    , @Time varchar(10) = '81244'


select convert(datetime, stuff(stuff(@date, 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-') + ' ' + stuff(stuff(right('0000' + @Time, 6), 3, 0,  ':'), 6, 0, '.'))
```